# How do I remove duplicate word in a cell in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I remove duplicates in the following case in T-SQL?

I have a table with a column `Code` of type `varchar(max)`.

It contains column value like `truck/rail/truck/rail`. I need the cell value to be `truck/rail`.

Other possibility is `truck/rail/ship/truck` need to be `truck/rail/ship`.

By using table valued function.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not such thing as a "cell" in SQL, that is spreadsheet terminology. Please provide a [mre] with sample data (ideally as DDL+DML), desired results and **your** attempt.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen SSMS 18

Comment: SSMS is just the tool to query a DB.. when you run the command select @@version in SSMS what do you get?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2019

Comment: @DaleK - Ok... you said not to call it a "cell".  You should turn your comment into an educational opportunity instead of just a criticism and tell the op what it IS called.

Comment: "Use table valued function" = prepare my homework

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String_Split` along with `String_agg` to remove the duplicates.

```sql
DECLARE @t table(id int, val varchar(max))

insert into @t values(1,'truck/rail/truck/rail'), (2,'truck/rail/ship/truck')

SELECT t.id,STRING_AGG(splitval,'/') as newval FROM @t as t
cross apply (
SELECT distinct value from string_split(t.val,'/')) as ca(splitval)
group by t.id
```

| id | newval |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rail/truck |
| 2 | rail/ship/truck |

**Note1:** `String_Split`, does not guarantee order. So, your concatenated results might be in different order from the original list, after duplicates removal. If you want to preserve the order, then we have to go for different solution using xml nodes or json array.

**Note2:** `String_Split` was introduced in SQL Server 2016. `String_agg` was introduced in SQL Server 2017. So, if you are using versions before that, you have to go for recursive CTE and CHARINDEX based solution.

Comment: Great answer, assuming OP has SQL 2017 or greater version.

Comment: Words should be in order if I have like truck/rail/ship/truck
I need truck/rail/ship

Comment: @Harry, thanks. yes. I have mentioned the same.

Answer (score -1):

If you know that the error exists, then just do an UPDATE where you replace the truck/rail/truck/rail with truck/rail using the REPLACE(Code,'truck/rail/truck/rail',truck/rail).

The same goes for your truck/rail/ship/truck issue.

If you need automatic detection and correction to be done, that's a whole 'nuther story but could still be done using nested REPLACES.  Detection of the issue is the hard part.  Personally, I'd be having a talk with the people that are providing the data.